# GKE Spring container - CloudSQL failing - 403 Forbidden

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-sql

I have a spring boot app that is failing to start in GKE engine

[image]

I can connect from local SQL developer to Cloud SQL , after running proxy

```
cloud_sql_proxy -instances=psomemy:europe-west2:pmydb=tcp:3306
```

I did not create a secret from Kubectl, as my connection string is

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql:///schema?cloudSqlInstance=myapp:europe-west2:mydbonly&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory
```

So I presume the below is not my scenario (?)
[image]

**How can I test access from my local postman or etc?**

Comment: Did you configure a service account for your deployment?

Comment: There are a few options, depending on connection string. I use socket factory in that container. Now I created service account, put the json in  environemnt prop,  and tested from laptop, but documentation seems to suggest that its not needed if app is in cloud. On the otherhand I have flyway, and I dont use flyway.user , password etc. I will let it use existing db credentials, is this a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a VM with default options (and it's the same thing with a cluster with node pool by default if you do nothing special), your Compute Engine uses the default service account with default scope.

[image]

And of course Cloud SQL scope isn't set by default

[image]

So, I recommend you to create a new node pool with:

- either the default service account and the correct scope granted
- or a custom service account (better solution)

But, the best solution is to use [Workload identity](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity). You can activate the add-on on your cluster, with recreating a pool, and you can set a service account for each pod, and therefore to go over the current scope limitation.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I enabled Cloud SQL. . I also made change to db connection from socker factory to  spring.cloud.gcp.sql.instance-connection-name model